# Append to a list does not work

Tags: python, append, dataframe

I have to add a column called 'sessions' to a dataframe called `merged1`. The column sessions is update in the loop and it is the list `y`. However the following operations don't work:

```
y.append(x * len(data))
merged1['sessions'] = y
```

Here the code

```
for i in users:
    merged1 = pd.DataFrame()
    name = "%s" %i
    y = list()
    for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        if os.path.isfile(file):    # make sure it's a file, not a directory entry
            if name in file:   # open file
                data = pd.read_csv(file)
                data = data.loc[[k for j, k in enumerate(data.index) if j % 10 == 0]]
                data.lat = np.round(data.lat, 6)
                merged1 = pd.concat([merged1,data], ignore_index=True)
                x = re.findall(r'(?<=_session)\d+', file)
                y.append(x * len(data))
    merged1['sessions'] = y
    if len(merged1) > 0:
        merged1 = merged1[merged1.lat > 45]
        merged1.to_csv(string,index=False)
```

Comment: what do you mean don't work , are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes sorry, the problem is that I am not  able to update the size of y in the loop and at the end I have that y as a differen len of merged1

Comment: `x * len(data)` looks fishy. It creates a list with multiple references to the list returned by `re.findall`.

Comment: Try `y.extend()` , instead of `y.append()` if you are sure `re.findall()` would only return 1 entry.

Comment: Thanks `y.extend()` works perfectly.

Comment: @AnandSKumar, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Kevin added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do -

```
y.append(x * len(data))
```

you are actually appending lists of size `len(data) * len(x)` into `y` so `y` becomes a list of lists.

Hence when you do - `merged1['sessions'] = y` - and the size of `y` differs from the size of `merged1` , it causes issues.

If you are sure that `x = re.findall(r'(?<=_session)\d+', file)` would always return only 1 element , then you can use -

```
y.extend(x * len(data))
```

instead of `.append()` . `.extend()` extends the list with the elements from the iterable that is passed to it.